# How to call Javascript when using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I am new to web development, I created a site where a person can go in and raise his vacation Request by clicking on the link from the home page. Once he clicks on Vacation Request link i used AJAX to display the vacation request form. 
Once he/she submits a vacation request i use Ajax to send the data to Servlet and display all his/her vacation request records under the Vacation Request form and this Vacation Request records display page has ******refresh button****. 
Now when i go back to home page and click on Vacation Request again and submit a Vacation Request and all his records display after he submits but ----**when i click on refresh button i see the request is getting displayed twice....**

**If i repeat the steps (like going to homepage->Vacation Request->submit Request->all records display-> click on Refresh button in the records page -> I see it is been submitted 3 times.**

So it is getting increment and looks like the Javascript file that i have in the  tag in the Record Display page is copying again and again and submitting page again and again.

Sorry for long note...**please** suggest me how to avoid this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your AJAX code? How does it get fired?

Comment: I have Jquery click function..when i click on the Refresh link it gets fired.